# Handle Conflicts Between Document Click and Element Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a dropdown, which I hide and show based on an element click. However, I also want to hide this dropdown whenever it is visible if I click anywhere else in the document.

This is the dropdown code:

```
function dropdown(){
    $('#smenubutton').click(function(e){
        var submenu = $(this).find('.submenu');

        if (submenu.is(':visible')){
            submenu.hide();
        }else{
            submenu.show();
        }
    });
}
```

however, a code like this:

```
 $(document).click(function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            $('.submenu').hide();
        });
```

will obviously always hide the submenu. both are loaded in document load. I know I am just missing something so simple. Feel free to point me to a duplicate(I have tried searching but can't find any questions based on my needs) and close this question.

Comment: Put `e.stopPropagation();` in the other event handler. You might also have to stop the event propagation when `submenu` is clicked.

Comment: You can't fire any events if you click outside of the browser :p. I think you meant outside the object '#smenubutton'.

Comment: yes indeed, reporter, thanks. editing now

Comment: @reporter: Sure you can, check my answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if  e.target is the submenu and hide the submenu only if it's not (in this case i check if it has the class submenu)

```
$(document).click(function(e){
            if($(e.target).hasClass("submenu")){ 
              $('.submenu').hide();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned "outside the browser", try this: http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/detect-browser-window-focus

EDIT: Since OP edited the question, I'll edit the answer:

```
$(document).on('click', '#submenu', function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   // show or hide the submenu here
});
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
   // hide submenu here
});
```

**example**: http://jsfiddle.net/A3SfP/

Comment: Thanks for the very interessting link at top of your answer. So I added this question to my favortis :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try on `blur()` or `focusout()`:

```
$('#smenubutton').blur(function(){ submenu.hide(); });
// OR
$('#smenubutton').focusout(function(){ submenu.hide(); });
```

If it doesn't work try giving your menu an explicit `tabindex`.